# Bandcamp bookmarklet not working

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I use this script to generate download links :

```
javascript: (function () {
  function callback() {
    (function ($) {
      var jQuery = $;
      window.files = new Array;
      window.i = 0;
      grabFiles();
      window.i = 0;
      $("#track_table div.dl_link").each(function (index) {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).html('<a href="' + window.files[i] + '">download</a>');
        window.i = window.i + 1;
      });

      function grabFiles() {
        $(TralbumData.trackinfo).each(function (index) {
          window.files[i] = this['file']['mp3-128'];
          window.i = window.i + 1;
        });
      }
    })(jQuery.noConflict(true))
  }
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
  if (s.addEventListener) {
    s.addEventListener("load", callback, false)
  } else if (s.readyState) {
    s.onreadystatechange = callback
  }
  document.body.appendChild(s);
})()
```

I discovered a page where it doesn't work :
[A Bird Story «OST»](http://freebirdgames.bandcamp.com/album/a-bird-story-ost)

It can get the download link of the first track, but it don't wan't to show it.

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: What does the Javascript console say? Could it be some encoding issue?

Comment: I wasn't looking the console. It was telling me that there was no such "mp3-128". xD

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to question titles, for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/130770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. x)

There was something missing  in the **grabFiles** function :

```
function grabFiles() {
  $(TralbumData.trackinfo).each(function (index) {
    if (this['file'] != null) {
      window.files[i] = this['file']['mp3-128'];
    }
    window.i = window.i + 1;
  });
}
```

Now, it will not try to read the non-existing **mp3-128** value when **file** is *null*. ^^;